# How Can I Make This Object Shoot Projectiles?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an ice [object](https://gyazo.com/369b47390a23075ed30d1be6e22ace36) my question is how can I make it shoot projectiles or make projectiles come out of it 1 by 1
for example: how could I make it shoot projectiles from its tip and it keeps falling tell the end of the screen

this is my ice object class

```
smallice = pygame.image.load("fals.png")
class smallice:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
       self.color = color
       self.smallice = pygame.image.load("fals.png")
       self.smallice = pygame.transform.scale(self.smallice,(self.smallice.get_width()-2,self.smallice.get_height()-2))
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
       # the hitbox our projectiles will be colliding with
       self.hitbox = (self.x + 0, self.y + 1, 10, 72)
   def draw(self):
       self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
       player_rect = self.smallice.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
       player_rect.centerx += 0 # 10 is just an example
       player_rect.centery += 70 # 15 is just an example
       window.blit(self.smallice, player_rect)

# define the small ices
black = (0,0,0)
smallice1 = smallice(550,215,20,20,black)
small = [smallice1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by making a `Bullet` class, for example, something like this:

```
class Bullet():

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.v = 5

    def fire_bullet(self,window):

        pg.draw.circle(window, (255,0,0), (self.x,self.y), 5)                         
        ice.fire = False

    def collision_box(self):

        collide = pg.Rect(self.x-offset_x, self.y-offset_y, size_x, size_y)
        return collide
```

Bullets will be simple circles, `self.v` stands for velocity. And `collision_box` will be use to detect the possible collision.

Now in your `main_loop` you need to detect when the ice object "wants to fire", simple example:

```
if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
    if len(bullets) < 2:
        ice.fire = True
```

And:

```
if ice.fire:        
        bullet = Bullet(round(y.x+offset), round(player.y+offset))
        bullets.append(bullet)
```

Now `len(bullets)` appeared, `bullets` is a list in which you will add a `bullet` object when the bullet is fired and remove it when the collision is detected or bullet goes outside of the chosen area. With this you can control the number of the bullets on the screen and also loop through it and call `collision()` method to see if one (or more) of them had collided, and keep track if it is still on the screen.

And if you want to shoot randomly then here is one basic idea:

```
if round(pg.time.get_ticks()/1000) % 3 == 0:
    ice.fire = True
```

The last part, going through the list, and some simple logic:

```
if bullets != []:                                                                   #Firing bullets
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet.fire_bullet(window)

            if bullet.y < screen_y:                                         #Bullet movement
                    bullet.x += bullet.v

            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))                                      #Poping bullets from list

            if bullet.collision_box().colliderect(other_rect_object):        #Bullet collision with other object
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
```

I am assuming (from the screenshot) that you want to shoot bullets down and only (vertically) hence the `bullet.y += bullet.v` and no direction flag.

This is simple code and idea, and ofcourse there is a lot room for improvement, but the approach works.
I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: this is what I did in my main loop https://gyazo.com/056b0ad8bfa9c1449ab6794f3487ac5a but I am getting an error  'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'fire' I changed my bullet class to enemybullets this part suppose to fire its self I didnt use the click a button to make it shoot I used the auto firing you provided

Comment: Could you provide the bullet class code, or the whole code. If it is long you can use pasteubuntu. From your comment I suspect you used same variable name twice and bullet got overwritten with image for example, but I can not be sure.

Comment: so sorry for the late reply here https://pastebin.com/raw/wETHBK6Y

Comment: Do not worry about that, you reply when you have time. You never instatiate the objects of the `enemybullets` class. As far as I see, in this line `new_bullet = projectile(start_x, start_y, dir_x/distance, dir_y/distance, (0,0,0))` you should use mentioned class instead of this one. Also use first Capital letter in class names.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e7188ed45daf48e24571ae2c75e290b1 this is what I have done for the bottom I want it to auto shoot bullets put I still keep getting the same error `    if ice.fire:
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'fire'` I used the same class as the one you gave me [class](https://gyazo.com/085fa3c71c19120f9783453e24ae1687)

Comment: `ice` is a picture aka `surface`. In this line `ice = pygame.image.load("ice1.png")`. So, image does not have attribute `fire`. You need to create new class (or not if you already have) which will have attribute (or in this case bool) `fire` and instantiate new object(s). Now the ice.fire or whatever you name that object will not result in AttributeError